# SQL Server Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server, casting

I am trying to pull some Active warranty data using the following code
The data that i am pulling to understand the failure rate

In order to avoid null i am using ISNUll

```sql
,isnull(cast(count(a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID])as varchar(10)),0) as 'DSPCH_QTY'
,isnull(cast(sum(a.[REPEAT_DSPCH_DEFECT_FLG])as varchar(10)),0) as 'RPT_QTY'
,isnull(cast(sum(a.[RDR_28])as varchar(10)),0)as 'RPT28_QTY'
,isnull(cast(Sum(a.[REPEAT_DSPCH_QUALIFY_FLG])as varchar(10)),0) as 'Qualify_QTY'
```

but i am getting an error Error converting data type varchar to float.

Can any one help me with the same.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Even worse, you alias different objects with the same alias in different scopes within the same query. Put this along side the lack of good indenting, and this is *very* difficult to read.

Comment: Are you certain your error occurs here? This shouldn't throw an error of 'converting data type varchar to float'. Since here you're casting, presumeably, a float to a varchar (other way around). If you are certain, you're probably trying to sum up alpha numerical values.

Comment: It makes little sense to use ISNULL and supply a numeric alternative value for null values when it seems obvious that you desire strings. In turn, presentation of values is a task that is better done by the consumer of your resultset and not in the query. But if you want help, you need to post the complete query (better yet - a scaled-down version that generates your error).

Comment: Yeah i understood the problem. The problem was both the tables where using different data types. So i changed the table data values and vola it got fixed. I could have use cast as well.